# Apple Watch - how do I schedule a complication update to be in synch with Push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I am writing a conference App in which participants can check the schedule of talks, with time and room number. User's select the talks they are interested in. The watch app displays the user's next upcoming talk as a complication.

In case a talk is delayed or has a room change we will send push notifications to all attendees for that talk. The app also updates the complication at regular intervals (every 30 minutes) If the user picks the push notification on her app or watch, the complication gets updated.

There is one use case for this setup which does not jive: 
If a push notification is received on the phone or app and the user sees the room time change on the push but does NOT pick the push, then the message on the push will be out of synch with the complication.

For example: The complication shows:
1:15p Rm 1F
Complication is scheduled for a 30 min interval update.
The push comes in at 1:10pm with "Your next event 'Global Warming' is delayed to 1:45pm" but the user does not pick it. Complication will continue to show 1:15pm until 1:30pm

Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement Background Fetch and force the complication update, this way you will have next schemes:

iOS:
Implement   `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` on the `UIApplicationDelegate` and fetch there a push notification. After that transfer fetched data using `WatchConnectivity` to Watch and force the complication update.

watchOS:
Implement `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` on the `WKExtensionDelegate` and just force the complication update after the successful fetching.

Comment: Not really, from my understanding, nothing in the app gets called unless the user picks the received notification.

Comment: You're wrong, all mentioned above methods are called independently of user actions and I've already used this feature in my projects. Just read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @CoolDocMan just in case will leave appropriate links here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: and https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKExtensionDelegate/didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Comment: I will try it out and get back to you. Will send you a virtual beer if it works :-)